# Can I store the path of an image as a variable and use it as given below

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-firestore

```
firestore.collection("products").where("OrderNo", "==", inputx)
.get()
.then(function(querySnapshot) { 
    querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
        var Nameout=doc.get("Name");
        var path='products/'inputx'-'Nameout;

        var tangRef = storageRef.child(path);

            }).then(function(){
            }).catch(function(error){
            })
```

ideally the path should be something like (products/123-image.jpg). Is there another way to store path to a variable

> var path='products/'inputx'-'Nameout; ==> this does not work!!

Comment: Use `+` to concatenate strings...  `var path='products/' + inputx + '-' + Nameout;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use back-tick

```
var path=`products/${inputx}-${Nameout}`;
```

or string concatenation

```
var path='products/' + inputx + '-' + Nameout;
```

Answer (score 1):

`var path = 'products/ ' + inputx + '-' + nameout;`

Or

`var path = 'products/{0}-{1}', inputx, nameout;`